# Why composer can not find my brand new package on packagist.org?

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I've just created my first [component](https://packagist.org/packages/components/greenshock-js) on packagist.org, this is a forked version of [greensock-js](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/).

I put `"components/greensock-js": "1.11.*@dev"` into the require section of my composer.json file, but the issue is composer can't find this package, saying

> no matching package found.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I made a typo in greenshock, correct: greensock. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now working fine:

```
$ c show components/greenshock-js
name     : components/greenshock-js
descrip. : GSAP: Professional-Grade HTML5 Animation
keywords : JS, HTML5, component, animation, gsap
versions : dev-master, 1.11.x-dev
```

Most likely you just lacked some patience :) It can take up to 10minutes for changes to propagate to composer. This will hopefully be reduced in the future again as we improve the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Composer V1, it's worth noting that V1 packagist metadata is updated **much less frequently** since May '21, as mentioned [here](https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/).

> #### Reduced v1 metadata API update rate starting in May 2021
>
> The update rate for new versions will be reduced from every-minute currently to once every 15 minutes. This means new releases will take a few minutes longer to be available for installation with Composer 1.x.

> #### Restricted access to unused packages via the v1 metadata API starting in May 2021
>
> This means new packages and old unused packages will only be visible to Composer 2 until someone installs them, at which point they will become visible to Composer 1 as well (within 24h as this process happens on a nightly basis).

If a newly uploaded package is not found, and you are using composer V1, your options are:

- take the slower updates into account and **wait quite a bit longer**
- upgrade to composer V2. V2 packagist metadata is updated **much** faster than V1 ever was.

Answer (score -1):

> This means new packages and old unused packages will only be visible to Composer 2 until someone installs them, at which point they will become visible to Composer 1 as well (within 24h as this process happens on a nightly basis).

So looks like you need to install the package using Composer 2 and wait for 24 hrs for it to become available to be installed with Composer 1.